# iOS 10 iPhone app displaying at 3.5" on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios10, iphone-4

Can someone please help me understand this:

• The iPhone 4S (3.5" screen) doesn't support iOS 10.

• Only phones with a 4" screen support iOS 10.

• Why do iOS 10 iPhone apps display at 3.5" when running on an iPad?

Answer (score 1):

All iPads except the Pro have a screen size of 768x1024 points.

A 3.5" iPhone is 320x480 points. In compatibility mode at the 2x option, the 3.5" iPhone appears as 640x960 points.

A 4" iPhone is 320x568 points. So if it were to be displayed at the 2x option on an iPad, it would need 640x1136 points. That's bigger than the resolution of the iPad.

The version of iOS is irrelevant.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent an iPhone app from being used on iPad? It seems crazy to build a portrait iPhone app that works on all iOS 10 phones, just to then have an iPad with a massive screen force the app into displaying at a phone size it doesn't even support :/